# Touch ID/Apple ID gets reset after switching between multiple macOS installations

Tags: macos, partitioning, multi-boot, macbook, apple-id

I currently have macOS 10.15 Catalina beta installed on my machine (2019 MBP 15") for primary use. I also have a separate APFS volume with macOS Mojave installed (for 32-bit apps). I don't use Mojave day-to-day, so I don't need to bother with Touch ID or signing in with my Apple ID on that volume. However, every time I boot into my *Mojave* volume, then switch back to my *Catalina* volume, the *Catalina* volume forgets all of my Touch ID fingerprints and makes me sign back into my Apple ID.

Is a way to either:

1. Get the Mojave volume to "ignore" the Secure Enclave/Touch ID so my fingerprints don't reset and Apple ID stays signed in on Catalina (preferred), or
2. Get Touch ID and iCloud to work seamlessly on both installations?